# PHP: DatePicker/Calendar not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have two forms I named it main.php and sample.php.... For main.php I have a calendar/datepicker and its working. But then when I proceed to the next page or to the sample.php the calendar/datepicker its not displaying anymore... I just copy the codes from main.php to sample.php

Here's my code for main.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepickerfrom" ).datepicker();
});

$(function() {
$( "#datepickerto" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

From: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom"name="from"> To:  <input type="text" id="datepickerto"name="to">
```

And For sample.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>

$(function () {
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});

    $(function() {
    $( "#datepickerfrom" ).datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
    $( "#datepickerto" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    From: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom"name="from"> To:  <input type="text" id="datepickerto"name="to">

<?php
echo "<div><input type='checkbox' class='checkall'> Check all</div>";
?>
```

But in the sample.php I added a code for checkbox all where I also use a script...

Thanks/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are calling `jquery` two times in `sample.php`. Either remove

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

P.S `jquery-ui.js` should come after `jquery`

Comment: @curious_coder...thanks for the help.. I just removed the "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>"... :) its already works.. when I removed the other one its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You need those lines on sample.php, tried it, it worked.

Comment: @MichaelGoyote...sorry for late reply... Its already in my post I already include that in my sample.php